# Android - Getting users acquisitions metrics programmatically

Tags: android, google-play

In the Google Play console we can see users acquisitions metrics for deployed apps, and most importantly where did users came from (in store search, campaigns, third party link, etc...).
Is there a way get those metrics programmatically in the app? So I can have different UX for users coming from different places?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? do you have some working code for this? from what place have you start tracking your first installation? Have you added a broadcast receiver for listening to Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH or just wrote code in mainActivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Play Install Referrer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice.html#the_getinstallreferrer_method) and [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) which may do some of what you want.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be it. Any idea how can I test this with different referrer urls without uploading my app to the store?

Comment: Upload your app in an Alpha channel with only your test accounts having access

Comment: Have you resolved your issue? do you have some working code for this? from what place have you start tracking your first installation? Have you added a broadcast receiver for listening to Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH or just wrote code in mainActivity?